# Не могу разобраться с записью указателя на функцию С++

Tags: c++, c

```
void (*vlog_startup_routines[]) () = {teal_top_register, teal_memory_note_register, 0};
```

Объясните, что это за мура? Вроде как указатель на функцию, знак равенства сбивает с толку, не видел такой записи.

Comment: Похоже на массив указателей на функции. Запись действительно всегда непонятная и я видел советы что надо писать `typedef` для типа указателя на функцию чтобы облегчить понимание кода.

Comment: вам надо научиться читать подобный код, это несложно, вы идёте от имени переменной сначала вправо, потом влево. Тут это выглядит приблизительно так: 
1) смотрим вправо и видим, что vlog_startup_routines это массив

2) дальше справо ничего нет- смотрим влево, видим, что это массив указателей

3) теперь за скобками смтрим вправо, потом влево, и понимаем, что это указатели на функции

4) в результате получаем, что vlog_startup_routines - это массив указателей на функции возвращающие void

Answer (score 3):

Это массив указателей на функцию, при этом последний элемент в массиве - nullptr (видимо в качестве завершающего символа, хотя, учитывая, что это массив на стэке, не совсем понятно зачем)

Comment: Это как строки с завершающим нулём, чтобы понять где массив заканчивается в процессе итерации по массиву. В примере то он на стеке, а вот куда он дальше отдаётся и в каком виде, не известно. Может это параметр в какой-нибудь функции, которая ожидает что маркером последнего элемента будет `0`

Comment: @vegorov я в курсе всего этого (в скобках я написал "видимо в качестве завершающего символа"), и именно из-за этого "может" и написал что не "совсем понятно" (всмысле не хватает данных чтобы сказать почему запись такая)

Comment: Я просто расписал эти моменты подробнее. Вдруг пригодится кому-нибудь через пару лет, когда будут читать этот ответ придя сюда из выдачи гугла